# Add a class to ng-repeat if current date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some problems trying to tweak an answer from another member.
I'm using the same answer to modify to get the logic right before I adapt to my needs.

[Original Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141183/display-today-birthday-using-angular)

Basically rather than toggling todays birthday (if it exists) I want to show it and add a class for styling and also remove it from the list to avoid repetition.

I'm new to Angular but slowly getting there but nothing I try is working.

I'm thinking I should use `ng-if="todayBirthday ? onlyToday(friend) : true"` to check if the date is today but its not working.

Any ideas would help greatly.

Comment: have you got answer? or I should create fiddle

Comment: Hi @SaurabhAgrawal yes please or if you could take a look at this codepen https://codepen.io/mfos/pen/ZLNQpQ?editors=1111. It seems the ng-if is not working in firefox or safari on osx. It seems to just ignore it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for adding the CSS class for your custom styling.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends| orderBy:'fromNow'" 
    ng-class="{ customClass: todayBirthday && onlyToday(friend) }" >
```

**CSS**

```
.customClass {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Doesn't seem to work for me. I have a codepen i'm working on. http://codepen.io/mfos/pen/ZLNQpQ. Basically all I want to achieve is to add a class to the record if it matches the current date i.e. todays date.

Comment: Hi, I think I may have sorted it. Going to check a few things and will confirm back. Thanks.

Comment: your codepen seems to work fine. The only problem is its showing 2001 which will go if u specify year in your date as well

Comment: Please click on the star against the answer if it helped

Comment: Hi, I've come across another issue that I have only noticed now I'm running some tests. In safari (macOS) its not working as it should. Chrome is fine. A codepen to compare in Chrome and Safari.. https://codepen.io/mfos/pen/ZLNQpQ?editors=1111 It seems its not reading the ng_if but any help would be great to locate the source of the issue. Thanks.